# Pronunciation of inédit

Tags: prononciation

I would have imagined that the first syllable of inédit would be pronounced as in interdit. Is there a rule that dictates why it's more of an English "ee" sound?

Comment: After _in_ in _inérdit_,there is a voyel, so in is pronounced "i"+"n" and not as "in". While in _interdit_, _t_ is fllowing _in_, so it is pronounced as "in". I hope this makes sense

Comment: @Vega Sorry, but it's inédit, and vowel.

Comment: Yes, the rule is that é is not e. inédit = een-eh-dit. The verb forms are éditer. not: editer.

Comment: @Lambie, Oops, I am super clumsy  when typing. It's _inédit_, indeed and also vowel

Comment: Depending if the syllabus _in_ is followed by a vowel or a consonant, it will be pronounced differently

Comment: @Vega syllables, not syllabus. The difference is between **e** and **é**.

Comment: @Lambie, Okay, meet you at English language site